# Is there a way to create an Access database from a Visio database model?

Tags: ms-access, visio

I'm using the latest version of Visio Professional 2016, Office 2016 ProPlus, and I also have access to Visual Studio Enterprise 2015.

I am still learning databases, and I was wondering if there is a way to automatically create an Access database from a Visio model, or if I have to recreate it in Access manually. This seems like no-brainer functionality, yet I can't seem to find it. After searching on Google, apparently Viso Enterprise Architect has this feature, which is part of Visual Studio. But those forum threads were from a long time ago, so I'm not sure if downloading the 7GB VS ISO will be worth it in the end.

Access seems to have its own relationship modeling feature, but there doesn't appear to be any integration with Visio.

Answer (score 1):

Visio supports creating a data model from Access or SQL server (reverse engineering) but ONLY up to version 2010. Beyond that version, reverse engineering is not supported.

And the last version to support forward engineering (create a database from a diagram) was 2007, or 2002 (regardless, the feature is long gone).

So reverse or forward engineering is not supported in recent versions of Visio.

There are some add-ins that return this feature (forward) engineering to Visio 2010 such as this one.

http://forwardengineer.codeplex.com/

Not aware if above works in 2013, or 2016 – but trying and posting back likely would be of value to people here.

To answer your question: no, reverse or forward engineering of database diagrams is not supported in recent versions of Visio – it is now strictly a diagramming tool – but not one that actually works with databases.

Comment: Do you know why they removed this functionality? Too buggy? Too much work to develop for little reward? It seems like a pretty useful feature.

Comment: They decided to turn Visio into a diagram only tool (not a reverse engineer tool). The suggested workaround was to use Visual Studio. However, the latest versions also dropped the data diagramming tools.  So now the workaround is to the use the built-in SQL tools in the SQL management studio - but that solution does not apply to Access, or quite much any  ODBC database that Visio supported.  So yes, it was a useful feature. So Visio not a developers tool anymore.